# Is there a way to create a multilevel list with one number scheme?

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to create a multilevel list where the numbers are always advancing.
This is an example:

```
001) Topic 1
    002) Topic 1 Sub Topic 1
    003) Topic 1 Sub Topic 2
004) Topic 2
    005) Topic 2 Sub Topic 1
        006) Topic 2 Sub Topic 1 Sub Sub Topic 1
    007) Topic 2 Sub Topic 2
008) Topic 3
```

I have tried defining a new list, but they do not continue numbering from previous level. And every predefined list restarts numbering.

EDIT: The reason I want to do this is because I would like to translate these topics to an enumerated list for programming.

Comment: You can specify the start number for any sublist.

Comment: @DavidPostill But that is not automatically done, meaning for every level you would have to specify the start number.

Comment: There might be a way to do this using Word’s automatic numbering, but there is certainly a way to do it if you can use { SEQ } fields - is that an option?

Comment: Could you expound on that?  Never seen that before @yokki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this that uses Word's built-in numbering and the other main approach (use field codes) is usually unfamiliar for users and is also likely to cause some features to stop working as people expect (e.g. outlining, and the web/device-based versions of Word probably still don't support this).

But if you need to do it, what you need to do is

- define a paragraph style for each level that specifies no numbering but leaves space for a number
- insert a suitable field code at the beginning of every paragraph, and any additional characters that you need (e.g. in your example you might need ") followed by a tab character, which would all be handled automatically by Word in a normal multilevel list)
- if you use SEQ fields, you also need to remember to select the field codes and use F9 (Windows Word) to update them when you modify the numbering (e.g. insert/delete numbered paragraphs) as they do not "autoupdate"

A SEQ field just generates the next number in a sequence that you name. So to take your first two paragraphs as an example, you might start with

```
Topic 1
    Topic 1 Sub Topic 1
```

Then click in front of the first Topic 1, use ctrl-F9 to enter a pair of the special field code braces `{  }`, followed by `)<tab>` so you have

```
{  })  Topic 1
    Topic 1 Sub Topic 1
```

Between the `{  }`, type the text `SEQ a \#000` so you have

```
{ SEQ a \#000 })  Topic 1
    Topic 1 Sub Topic 1
```

Use Alt-F9 to toggle between field code view and field results view, then select the field and press F9 to update its result. In results view you should see

```
001)  Topic 1
    Topic 1 Sub Topic 1
```

Repeat for the second para. and you should see

```
001)  Topic 1
    002)  Topic 1 Sub Topic 1
```

The "a" in the SEQ field is the name of the sequence - you call call it "mylist" or some such instead. By default SEQ generates an Arabic number, and the `\#000` is a "numeric format" that left pads with zeroes.

If you use this approach, you would typically create an autotext or some such to insert the whole field.

You can put the ) inside the format if you prefer, like this:

```
{ SEQ a \#"000)<tab>" }
```

(where  is actually a tab character).

SEQ fields were the usual way to achieve multilevel numbering in the very early days of Windows word - they have the advantage of stability and not relying on structures that it is difficult to change in Word without using VBA.

However, Microsoft did introduce another field type, LISTNUM, which can insert the numbering from an existing list number style. In principle, the advantage is that LISTNUM numbers are updated automatically by Word. I have never seen them used in real-world situations. To use them, you first have to set up a named multilevel style. Word's terminology and behaviour seems very confused in this area - they use different term in the user interface and in Word's programming object model, and it is rarely clear whether you are creating something new, or modifying something that will cause your document's layout to change. Which is probably a major reason why people steer clear of this stuff.  But let's try to step through. I would only do this on a test document. The thing we are trying to set up is actually called a "ListTemplate" in Word's object model.

- Click in one of the paragraphs you want to number.
- Go into *Home->Paragraph->Multilevel list* and select *Define New Multilevel List...*
- Click the More >> button at the bottom left if it is showing.
- The dialog will probably show the set-up of an existing list template. We want to do our best not to disturb that, so the first thing to do is click the in the box on the right labelled *Listnum field list name* and give the ListTemplate a name, e.g. **list001**.
- Click on each number (1-9) under *Click level to modify* (at the top left) in turn, and in the *Link level to style* dropdown, select **No Style**
- Click on level 1 under *Click level to modify*.
- Delete everything in the *Enter formatting for number* box
- In the *Number style for this level* dropdown, select 001,002,003...
- Type a ")" after the number in the *Enter formatting for number* box
- I don't think any of the other settings in here are used when you use a LISTNUM field to insert the number, so click OK.

Now instead of inserting `{ SEQ a \#"000)<tab>" }` you need a field that looks like this:

```
{ LISTNUM list001 }
```

Unlike the SEQ field, you cannot apply a numeric format switch using `\#`, so

- you can't get the field to generate a following space or tab
- you can only use numbering formats that you can define in the *Enter formatting for number* box. For example, there is an 001 format, an 0001 format, an 00001 format but if you really needed 000001 the only way you could do it would be to insert a 0 at the beginning of the number format box (and your numbers would only run from 1 to 999999)

It's possible that this approach is more stable if you specify the "level number" (1, in this case) in the field, like this:

```
{ LISTNUM list001 \l 1 }
```

Finally, if you need to restart the numbering, for a SEQ field you can use the `\r`switch like this:

```
{ SEQ a \r 1 } - restarts numbering at 1
```

and with the LISTNUM you use the `\s` switch

```
{ LISTNUM list001 \s 1 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Could I add another <tab> to  the seq field to produce the intended level?

Comment: @MarkWalsh : you mean inside the numeric format? Pretty sure the answer is “yes” (can’t check right now) but I would think you could do that better in the Paragraph properties of whatever paragraph style you created.

Comment: Btw I can see I have lost a couple of backslashes by not formatting properly as code. Will fix later.

Comment: @MarkWalsh think I misunderstood your previous comment. If you mean “can I determine the paragraph style by using different numbers of tabs inside the field“ (cf. When you tab at the beginning of the paragraph to indent it more) then the answer is no, Not as far as I know.

Comment: I just tested with `{ SEQ a \#"{AUTOTEXT TAB1}000) "}`.  Where TAB0-TAB9 are autotext fields predefined as 0 to 9 tabs.  That seems to work.

Comment: @MarkWalsh. Neat, will try that when I can.

Comment: @MarkWalsh OK, I wasn't sure what you were doing there. IMO it's "whatever floats your boat" but I would probably (a) use styles for layout and (b) try to avoid AUTOTEXT because they aren't stored with the document, so anyone who tries to update these fields without the autotexts may run into trouble. I'd probably either hardcode them, e.g. use (say) { SET tab3 "<tab><tab><tab>" } in a header, then { tab3 } to insert it. Or use VBA to create Document variables (ActiveDocument.Docvariables("tab3").Value = string(3,chr(9)) then use { DOCVARIABLE tab3 }. Just my 2c-worth.